# Is there any way to make a captcha accessible in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, accessibility, captcha, coldfusion-10

I am using `<cfimage>` to create a captcha.  Is there any way to make this vision impaired accessible.  On other websites I've seen, you can click something that will read it to you.  Is this possible in ColdFusion?  Currently using CF10 but can upgrade to newer version if needed to in order to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not an option for cfimage.

I would recommend you look at recaptcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/